# CakePHP find all not setting values to variables. All other find functions working

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

In my controller I have two functions that pull all records from the db with a status = 4.  In one function it works fine.  I copied the find all statement from the working function:

```
$this->set('completed', $this->Topic->find('all', array('fields' => array(
                    'Topic.creator','Topic.link','Topic.id', 'Topic.topic_name', 'Topic.info', 'Topic.priority', 'Topic.user_id',
                    'Topic.completed','Topic.created', 'Topic.status','User.name','User.id','Topic.category','Topic.tags'),'conditions' => array(
                    'Topic.status' => 4))));
```

But in the new function the `$completed` array doesn't seem to exist.  The debug statement is just a blank line.  If I debug the sql log using `debug($this->Topic->getDataSource()->getLog());` this is the returned array:

```
Array
(
[log] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [query] => SELECT `Topic`.`creator`, `Topic`.`link`, `Topic`.`id`, `Topic`.`topic_name`, `Topic`.`info`, `Topic`.`priority`, `Topic`.`user_id`, `Topic`.`completed`, `Topic`.`created`, `Topic`.`status`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`id`, `Topic`.`category`, `Topic`.`tags` FROM `topics` AS `Topic` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Topic`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `events` AS `Event` ON (`Event`.`topic_id` = `Topic`.`id`)  WHERE `Topic`.`status` = 4
                [affected] => 9
                [numRows] => 9
                [took] => 0
            )

    )

[count] => 1
[time] => 0
)
```

The SQL statement in the log works.  If I plug in into mySQL it produces results.  And the affected and numRows field show the correct number of records.  But the produced data isn't being set to variables.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  My boss and I are stumped.  Here are both complete functions:

```
         public function dashboard(){
            $this->set('completed', $this->Topic->find('all', array('fields' => array(
                    'Topic.creator','Topic.link','Topic.id', 'Topic.topic_name', 'Topic.info', 'Topic.priority', 'Topic.user_id',
                    'Topic.completed','Topic.created', 'Topic.status','User.name','User.id','Topic.category','Topic.tags'),'conditions' => array(
                    'Topic.status' => 4))));
            $this->set('total_inprogress_release', $this->Topic->find('count', array('conditions' => array(
                    'OR' => array('status <>' => 4,'status <>' => 0),
                    'priority' => 4))));
    $this->set('upcoming_events', $this->Topic->Event->find('all'));
            $this->Topic->virtualFields['count'] = 'COUNT(*)';
            $this->set('graph_data', $this->Topic->find('chart', array('fields' => array('status_txt', 'priority_txt', 'count'), 'group' => array('status', 'priority'),
                    'chart' => array(
                            'xaxisTitle' => 'Status',
                            'yaxisLabels' => array('Release', 'Company', 'News'),
                            'xaxisLabels' => array('Open','In Progress','Completed'),
                            'yaxis' => 'Topic.priority_txt',
                            'xaxis' => 'Topic.status_txt',
                            'data' => 'Topic.count'
            ))));
    }
```

And here's the nonworking function:

```
        public function completed(){
            $foo = $this->Topic->find('all', array('fields' => array(
                    'Topic.creator','Topic.link','Topic.id', 'Topic.topic_name', 'Topic.info', 'Topic.priority', 'Topic.user_id',
                    'Topic.completed','Topic.created', 'Topic.status','User.name','User.id','Topic.category','Topic.tags'),'conditions' => array(
                    'Topic.status' => 4)));
            debug($foo);
            debug($this->Topic->getDataSource()->getLog());


    }
```

Comment: try `$foo = $this->Topic->find('all', <snip>); debug($foo); exit;` in your controller, before going any further. does `$foo` contain any data?

Comment: I tried that and there's still no data.  I also edited the question.  I said the $completed array was blank.  What I mean is that there is no array.  The debug statment produces a blank line, not even an empty array.

Comment: Also @Ross, thanks for reformatting the array.  I should have done that in the first place.

Comment: perhaps post both functions in their completeness, if possible? there must be something else going on

Comment: Is it correct that you want to use the $completed var, which you set in a function, in another function? Set is used to send the variable to the view...

Comment: No, the functions are standalone.  I have two seperate views, both showing the same data.  The views format the data differently though, one listing and one incorporating into a graph.

Comment: try a `var_dump` instead of a debug

Comment: also you might want to check for any beforeFind callback methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of tracking the data until we figured out where it was being lost, we found that the problem was some of the data in the database.  It was encoded and it was causing a `while` statement in the core cake files to reset when it encountered said data.  The solution was to alter `Config/database.php` as such:
    class DATABASE_CONFIG {

```
    public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'login',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'database' => 'database',
            'prefix' => '',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',//this line allows the database to read utf8 data.
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the relationships may be causing an issue here. Try this in the completed function and `pr($foo)` the results:

```
$foo = $this->Topic->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Topic.creator',
        'Topic.link',
        'Topic.id', 
        'Topic.topic_name', 
        'Topic.info', 
        'Topic.priority', 
        'Topic.user_id',
        'Topic.completed',
        'Topic.created', 
        'Topic.status',
        'User.name',
        'User.id',
        'Topic.category',
        'Topic.tags'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Topic.status' => 4,
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Topic.user_id = User.id'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'recursive' => -1,
));
```

I suspect you will get the results you are looking for.